# Mysql Multiple tables relationship structure

Tags: mysql, relationship

I have a users table, an asset table (contains for example a record with value equal to favorite_movie), and than a user_to_asset table (containing userid,assetid,and value, such as 'american history x').

I was thinking if there would be a point to have a type id also, along with a type table ofcourse, for example a type could be user preferences or user details.... so in the end, the user_to_asset table would then contain a userid,typeid,assetid, and value (ofcourse i would have to change the table name bc weve now included typeid within the user_to_asset table).. maybe it would optimize my code since for instance i can query all preferences for a user by just querying the user_to_assets table by typeid equal to user preference and user_id equal to the user.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the following tables:

- user (user_id, user_name, email, theme_id)
- asset (asset_id, asset_type_id, asset_name, etc)
- user_to_asset (user_id, asset_id)
- theme (theme_id, themestuff)
- asset_type (asset_type_id, asset_type)

This allows you to say:

Show me all the assets of type "movie" for user "Jonathan" while applying Jonathan's theme to the result.

Comment: types is the type of asset, not a user type. for example, an asset would be favorite movie, and type of this asset would be user details. Another example would be an asset and the type of asset is user preferences (notice the difference between user details and user preferences, those would be the asset type) Does that make sense? Do I need to have a type of asset?

Comment: I think I am not understanding what a user preference is.

Comment: A user preference would be having a blue theme whereas a user detail would be primary emailaddress. I think Im going to get rid of this asset type field, it seems a bit ridiculous (unless you can see a reason to have an asset type assigned to a record).

Comment: precisely correct. you dont understand though, the theme would be an asset and the type of asset would be a user preference (so theres no need for a theme table). so, in general, is it necessary to have an asset type? is there any benefits?

Comment: If you want to be able to select assets by type you probably want to have an assets_type table.

Comment: precisely correct. you dont understand though, the theme would be an asset (the asset table would have a record of - {1,'theme'}, and the user_to_asset would have a record of - {1,1,'blue'} - signifying the primary id, the asset id, and the asset value. now, with that being said, is there any reason to add into the user_to_asset table an asset_type_id, making a primary id, an asset_type_id, an asset_id, and the value.

Comment: I don't think that a theme is an asset in the same way that favorite movie is an asset.  Seems to me that themes should not be stored in the assets table.

Comment: i think weve worked this out to a point where i know what i want to do. thanks for working this out with me. im going to use an asset type to distinguish between different types of assets.

Comment: I editted your answer to be the acceptable answer. it will show the editted answer once it is peer reviewed apparently.